# Регистрация домена с IDN символами

Tags: домен, регистрация, поддомены

Добого всем,

Пытаюсь зарегистрировать домент с одним греческим (Modern Greek) символом в названии, но регистраторы отказывают это делать.

В интернете есть список:
https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/238/35/do-you-support-idn-domains-and-emoticons

Пробовал регистрировать в зонах .io, .uk и т.д.
Вбивал так же уже декодированное название в Punycode.

Есть где-нибудь проверенная информация на каких доменах это можно сделать
и каким образом правильно подавать регистрацию.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте через Ру-Центр (https://www.nic.ru/) или другого регистратора доменов, у которого явно прописано, что он поддерживает регистрацию IDN. Смотрите там список доменов с IDN (зеленая сноска после имени доменной зоны).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте конверторы **[Punicode](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)** для символов. Например **[URL Decoder/Encoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)** или **[Punycode converter](https://www.punycoder.com/)**. Надеюсь, что это поможет.